# Combinatorics Drugs Distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Someone already asked this question, but I wanted to know why the answer isn't 
$
 {50\choose20} + {30 \choose 20 }+ {10 \choose 10 }
$
instead it's $
 {50\choose20} \cdot {30 \choose 20 } \cdot {10 \choose 10 }
$

In a medical experiment involving $50$ patients, $20$ patients are chosen to receive drug X, $20$ patients are chosen to receive drug Y, and $10$ patients are chosen to receive no drug. In how many different ways can the treatments for the $50$ patients be assigned?

Comment: For **every way**  of choosing who gets X, there are $\binom{30}{20}$ ways to choose who gets Y.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because the combinations aren't disjoint, so the rule of product says to multiply. Let's examine a problem where we have disjoint events to shed some light on this. So we have a lottery where we pick five balls out of fifty. I want to know how many ways can I get exactly one ball correct. That would be $\binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{45}{4}$. Now if I wanted exactly two balls correct, then I would have $\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{45}{3}$. Since it is impossible to get exactly one and two balls in the same event, these events are disjoint, and so I add them:

$$\binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{45}{4} + \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{45}{3}$$

Now the drug example is hard to see because of its size. So let's consider a simpler example. If I have 5 people. I need two people to do task one, two people to do task two, and one person to do task three. So how many ways can I break everyone up into groups? Well, we have people $\{a, b, c, d, e\}$. So for task one, I can have: $ab, ac, ad, ae, bc, bd, be, cd, ce, de$. That's clearly $\binom{5}{2}$ people, right?

Now if I fix $ab$, in how many ways can I choose group two? I can choose $cd, ce, de$. That's $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. What if I instead fix $ce$ for task one? Then I have $ab, ad, bd$ for group two options. That's again, $\binom{3}{2}$ options. Notice that each time I fix group one, I have $\binom{3}{2}$ options for group two. So there are $\binom{5}{2}$ options for group one, right? And $\binom{3}{2}$ options for group two given each configuration of group one? So it's easy to see the multiplication: $\binom{5}{2} \binom{3}{2}$. And of course, after we pick our first two groups, we only have one person left over, so we multiply by $1$.

The logic is the same in the drug problem you gave. I will be happy to go into it more if you want, but I hope my examples have helped you to see what's going on at a smaller scale.